# Применить bootstrap только в одном компоненте Next.js приложения

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, nextjs

С сервера приходит html, стилизованный с помощью bootstrap. Я установил для этого bootstrap (npm). Мне нужно, чтобы стили бутстрап применялись только в этом компоненте.

В файле компонента импортирую либу

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Проблема в том, что стили бутстрап применяются по всему приложению. В частности отступы какие-то дефолтные.

Как сделать так, чтобы стили bootstrap применялись только в этом компоненте?

Comment: Никак. css расспространяются на весь HTML документ. Если компонент - это целая страница(пусть и виртуальная), то можно добавлять отдельно css bootstrap, а на других страницах его удалять. Костыльно/кривовато, но других вариантов я не вижу.